# SQL Return only those of certain age

Tags: mysql

I have this sql statment:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%Y') - $strYear)<=3
```

Which works, kinda, but if the year of the DOB is more (later) than $strYear it goes wrong.

ie.

```
 strYear = 1960
 dob(Y) = 1930
```

`1930 - 1960 = -30` which fulfills the `<=3` condition, but is obviously wrong as I'm looking for users within in 3 year range.

Any ideas?

Comment: AND (DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%Y') - $strYear) > 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%Y') - $strYear) <= 3 
AND (DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%Y') - $strYear) > 0
```

That might work.

Answer (score 0):

$strYear seems like PHP variable...

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users
          WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%Y')-$strYear)<=3
            AND (DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%Y')-$strYear) > 0"
```

and difference should be greater than 0

Comment: No. Using ABS doesn't help here. Think about DOB = 1930, strYear = 1932. You'd get an incorrect result returned with ABS(-2) <= 3.

Comment: Pardon? Have you just repeated my statement? Yes, $strYear is PHP.

Comment: @Joe - your right I wrong interpreted second condition > 0 is needed - fixed